# Including an array of files in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller

what i'm  trying to do is include all the php files in a given directory into the main php file, I'm loading them into an array using `Glob()`

like so:

```
// get all php files  
$files = glob('*.php');
```

But when I try to `include($files)` I'm getting an error saying it doesn't like arrays, should I use a foreach statement? or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: No, foreach would be the most concise option there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd use a foreach statement, so foreach $files as $file, include($file).

Having said that, I'm not so sure it's a good idea from a security point of view because you're just hoovering up every file in a directory and including it - if a malicious file gets onto your server then glob() leaves you with no way to evaluate whether or not it ought to be there before it's included and parsed.

Comment: I was more doing this as a proof of concept than a production application. I'm not too concerned about the security side, thanks for the input though.

Comment: Nicely - glob is a useful (and underused) function but it's worth noting the security implications for other folks who might stumble across it. :)

Answer (score 0):

[**`include()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) doesn't accept an array of files -- it only accept one file path as a parameter.

This means you have to loop over that array of files, **including one file at a time** :

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    include $file;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`foreach`
 (I need to put at least 30 characters)

Comment: The requirement to write at least 30 characters is there to persuade you to write full, descriptive sentences, not to write meaningless filler after your too-short answer.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal sorry - do not take this personaly